# How can I hide user's id and password from URL?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a web page where users can view and edit their application information. I have an Edit button. When a user clicks on this button it takes him to an edit page. Here is my code:

```
<form name="form3" method="post" action="pages/application_edit.php?id=<?php echo "$id[0]";?>&pwd=<?php echo "$pwd";?>">  
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Edit Application" class="button"> 
</form>`
After a click the user sees this URL:`http://website.com/pages/application_edit.php?id=1&password=Flower1
```

How can I hide the password from the URL?

Comment: Is it really necessary to pass user password on that call?

Comment: @nargis why would you even want to send the password to edit page?

Comment: Why do you need to send the user's authentication credentials in the first place?  It seems like you should have a separate authentication mechanism entirely which supplies the user with a token or begins a session of some kind to track the user, rather than passing along credentials with every page.

Comment: I am passing user password because once you login a user is able to view another user's application by simply changing the ID number in the URL.That's why I added the password.

Comment: Yeah no ouch the security risks are painful with this... try looking into how $_SESSION superglobal works, that might help you..

Comment: I don't know your app context, but it seems an Edit session should be available after user authentication, which itself eliminates the need to send passwords. Even if users can see each others details and edit it, still doesn't make any sense sending passwords around.

Comment: I agree with @David. I am just very new to programming. That's why could not build stronger system.

Comment: @Nargis try to send only the id in url and encrypt it via some algo so that you can decrypt it in another page.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers. I appreciate. I am having hard time implementing these. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the values as $_GET values, send them as $_POST values to that PHP page.

```
<form method="POST" action="pages/application_edit.php"> // no need for the URL query string
```

In the PHP file

```
<?php 
    $user_id = $_POST['id']; // similar to how you'd use $_GET
....
```

Although the way you're approaching this is wrong, you shouldn't be passing these values between pages. At the very least your username/id should be stored as a session variable and information should be accessed when required from a database.

Either way, that's how you can send them without having them "visible".

Comment: you need to specify method = "Post" also. default value of method is "GET"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you lack session control routines.

You should manage all *private options* of your application (the ones you are able to perform only - and just only - when you are logged in) inside a **session** to avoid exposing user credentials.

You can start learning about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Also, consider encrypting your HTTP requests using SSL certificate.